# Return the index of a matrix within an array, based on a condition

Tags: r

Hi everyone,
            I have an array of matrices of 1's and 0's. For each row (which represents an individual), I want to know the index of the matrix (dimension z) where the first 1 appears.

I've tried to create a function to be applied to the array, returning a vector with the index of the matrix for each individual.

```
A= rbind(c(1,0),c(0,0))
B=rbind(c(0,1),c(1,0))
c<- array( c( A , B) , dim = c( 2 , 2 , 2 ) )

get.first <- function(x)min(which(x !=0 ))
f <- sapply( c,get.first)
```

I would like the resulting vector f to be equal to

f=c(1,2) meaning the first individual was recorded in the first matrix  and the second individual in the second matrix.

The message error returns 4 times

1: In min(which(x != 0)) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `apply` rather than just `sapply`, and tell `apply` which margin to map `get.first` over.

`apply(c,3,get.first)` evaluates to `c(1,2)`.

Tangentially, using `c` as the name of an array is a bit confusing, since `c` is also the name of a core R function.

Comment: Terrific John. Thank you very much. Do you know how to make the function work if in addition I have NAs sparse over the matrix? Have tried a couple of options but no success so far. Thanks again

Comment: @user2654444 Glad I could help. If it adequately answers the question, you could consider marking the answer as "accepted". As far as your other question goes, it isn't clear to me how you want the output to be with NAs. Do you want to treat them as zeros? If so just use `which(x!=0 & !is.na(x))`. If something more is needed, post as a new question.

Comment: The new question is posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295852/return-the-index-of-a-matrix-with-nas-within-an-array-based-on-a-condition . For some reason, it does not work with NA's.