# Return the index of a matrix with NAs within an array, based on a condition

Tags: r

I have an array of matrices of 1's, 0's and NAs. For each row (which represents an individual), I want to know the index of the matrix (dimension z) where the first 1 appears.

I've tried to create a function to be applied to the array, returning a vector with the index of the matrix for each individual.

```
A= rbind(c(NA,1),c(0,0))
B=rbind(c(0,1),c(1,0))
d<- array( c( A , B) , dim = c( 2 , 2 , 2 ) )

    get.first <- function  (x) min(which(x!= 0 & !is.na(x)), na.rm = TRUE)
    f <- apply( d,3,get.first)
```

I would like the resulting vector f to be equal to

`f=c(1,2)`

meaning the first individual was recorded in the first matrix and the second individual in the second matrix.

instead I get a vector 
`f = c(3,2)` 
but the array has only two matrices, which is odd

Comment: Well in the first matrix the 3rd element is one and in the second matrix 2nd element is one. I am not sure what exactly you want to get that the desired output will be translated to `c(1,2)`. Can you elaborate? p.s. It is not clear to me what you are trying to say by *"For each row (which represents an individual), I want to know the index of the matrix (dimension z) where the first 1 appears."*

Comment: Certainly. Each row represents the history  of detection of an individual (1 (detected, 0 (not detected or NAs) and z (3rd dimmension array index) indexes represent different times where surveys where conducted. I want my function to tell me at what time was the individual first detected. Individual 1 (row 1) was first detected in the first matrix d[,,1] and individual 2 in the second. Does this make sense?